# Make the syntax highlighting in Pycharm good as Sublime Text 3

Tags: pycharm, sublimetext

To me, it seems like the syntax is much more clear and easy to read in Sublime (note the differences between the color of the function of the Regex).

*Pycharm*:

[image]

*Sublime*:

[image]

Is there any way to make Pycharm highlight the text in the same colors as Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the coloring scheme of pycharm IDE. In the Settings/Preferences dialog ( Ctrl+Alt+S ), go to Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Semantic highlighting.
Here you can read more.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html